# ¿Cómo hacer que según el color del input, se pinte un Div?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un `<input type="color"` y lo que quiero es que según el color que se seleccione, el fondo de un Div se pinte de ese color (si cambio de naranja a verde, por ejemplo que haga el cambio)

HTML:

```
<div class="p1">p1</div>
<input type="color" class="Color1">
```

De Javascript no tengo nada, porque no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo, soy nuevo en JS.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Lo logras de está manera,tienes que añadir un controlador de eventos al control `html` y hacer la lógica que necesitas.

`const elementDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("p1")[0];
elementDiv.style.height = "250px";
elementDiv.style.width = "250px";
document.getElementsByClassName("Color1")[0].addEventListener("change", () => {
    elementDiv.style.background = "red";
}, false);`